# Download all links in a .json file with Python

Tags: python, json, download

I have a .json file with hundreds of links in it.  How do I download them all with a Python script?

is this how I start?

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import uuid

with open('db.json') as data:
    data = json.load(data)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Could you post a short snippet of the JSON data you are parsing and a quick example of what you would like to gather?

Comment: https://github.com/tsuhgi/champion-spell-info-builder/blob/master/db.json  This is the json file. I was originally going to try to download only a few of the links, but it was hard to differentiate.  So now I would just like to go through all the links and download them all (every link is an image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download the JSON data, iterate over JSON field and getting `name` and `image` link, you can do like this :

```
import requests

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tsuhgi/champion-spell-info-builder/master/db.json"
data = requests.get(url).json()

for key in data:
    print("name {} | link {}".format(data[key]["name"], data[key]["img"]))
```

Comment: what does the example json look like? link's dead. specifically what is "name" and what's its relationship to the img url? thanks for this.